# What possible reason could there be for removing an element from a HashSet immediately prior to re-adding it?

Tags: java, set

I've stumbled across some code that is broadly along the following lines, but cannot for the life of me fathom why the author is attempting to remove `bar` from `bars` before then adding it:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

class Foo {

  private final Set<Object> bars = new HashSet<>();

  public void addBar(final Object bar) {
    bars.remove(bar);  // WHY ????
    bars.add(bar);
  }

  public Object[] getBars() {
    return bars.toArray(new Object[0]);
  }
}
```

All that I can come up with is that it's in anticipation of (or legacy from) a different `Set` implementation that's sensitive to insertion order, such as `java.util.LinkedHashSet` (although there's nothing about the code or use case that suggests insertion order would be of any interest) - but perhaps there's something else I'm missing?

Comment: Is that the entire code, or is something done with the `bar` instance between removing it from the Set and re-adding it?

Comment: @Eran Maybe that was actually happening at some point, but then someone did a refactor and removed that code, leaving behind what we see right now.

Comment: It depends. Perhaps there may be instances that are equal to the current instance but the application wants this particular instance. Context is required.

Comment: @Eran: No, the `add` operation immediately follows the `remove` with no other operations in between; nor can I envisage that there ever would have been any manipulation of `bar` because, whilst it is not actually immutable, it is essentially serving as a value type that may as well be.

Comment: This would have been a perfect example for the original developer to leave a comment about that I suppose...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a class `Bar` that has fields that are not included in the `equals` check then this code causes the new instance (with potentially different contents) to be in the Set vs. the old instance remaining in the Set:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Object> bars = new HashSet<Object>();
    Bar bar1 = new Bar(1, 2);
    Bar bar2 = new Bar(1, 3);

    bars.add(bar1);
    bars.add(bar2); // no effect since bar1.equals(bar2)
    // only bar1 in the set

    bars.remove(bar2); // removes bar1 since bar1.equals(bar2)
    bars.add(bar2);
    // only bar2 in the set
}

static class Bar {
    int field1;
    int field2;

    public Bar(int field1, int field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Bar)) return false;
        Bar bar = (Bar) o;
        return field1 == bar.field1;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(field1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is probably it.  There are indeed fields in `bar`'s type that are excluded from its `equals` check and there is also a second addition of instances to `bars` that does not first perform the removal.

Comment: @eggyal IMHO this is bad design. In this case I'd use a `HashMap` with a "key object" containing the fields that are currently used in `Bar`'s `equals` and associate the `Bar` instance as the value so you can just put unconditionally. The only other use case I can think of remove+add would be when having a set/map with insertion order and you want to "refresh" the position of the element (if the element is already there its insertion order does not change). But you wouldn't use `HashSet` for that.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: I completely agree, it's hiding intent in a horrible way!  But before I could begin refactoring, I first needed to figure out the intent...